# ValueError: Didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem when I want to edit my post. When I press edit - I have this problem:

```
ValueError at /post/19/edit/
The view blog.views.post_edit didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

*urls.py:*

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
```

*views.py:*

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

*post_edit.html:*

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong in a couple of places. You need to instantiate the blank form if the request is not POST; and you need to return in all circumstances. So:

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
     else:
        form = PostForm(instance=post)
     return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form':form})
```

Note how the `else` lines up with the first `if`, and the return is outside both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `request.method` is not `POST`. Just do:

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
        ....
        else:
        .....
    # return a response in cases when request.method is not POST
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Why? Presuming he returns a response in his `if form.is_valid():` and it's `else` the only thing he's missing is to return a response outside of his `if request.method =="POST"`. `return HttpResponse()` is just a pseudo.